# A strange C++ class declaration

Tags: c++

Have read this thread in stackoverflow: [Strange class declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148571/strange-class-declaration) 
, but still confused with below code in `foo.h`:

```
class Foo CHECKLEAKDCL {
```

I am sure that Foo should be the class name, since there are constructor and deconstructor which can imply this.

I cannot see any macro definition related with CHECKLEAKDCL in this .h file.

also I am confused with the answer for [Strange class declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148571/strange-class-declaration) , which saying that:

> Q_CORE_EXPORT isn't an identifier. It's a platform-dependent macro,
>   and it's used to signal a class that's intended to be used across
>   library boundaries.

Can anyone give some more explanation of this?

---

**UPDATE:**

found this line in a .h file, which is included in `foo.h`:

```
#define CHECKLEAKDCL  : private CheckLeak
```

so the class declarition should be :

```
class Foo : private CheckLeak {
```

So Foo is extending CheckLeak, right?

Comment: Search the whole project for `CHECKLEAKDCL`, it must be defined as a preprocessor macro somewhere.

Comment: Take a look to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840874/what-does-it-mean-when-a-class-declaration-appears-to-have-two-names I hope it helps you =D

Comment: Either that or `Foo` is defined as a preprocessor macro expanding to empty, or worse expanding to `{}; class`.

Comment: `#define CHECKLEAKDCL  : private CheckLeak` . Oh wow.

Comment: "extending" isn't a good metaphor. What you have is *private inheritance*. The base subobject is only accessible to the derived class itself, so I wouldn't call this an "extension".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you compile for windows (using Visual Studio), highly possible it will be evaluated to one of the Microsoft specific linkage identifiers, `dllexport` or `dllimport` :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81h27t8c.aspx

It is used when you create a class which will be exported from a DLL or used from a DLL in an application, and dependig of this it's either evaluated to `dllexport` (DLL exporting the class) or `dllimport` (Application importing the class).

If you compile with GCC possibly it will evaluate to one of the gcc `_-attribute__`s. Such as `__attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))` (https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility)

These extensions to the core C++ are provided by compilers to make certain tasks more easily achievable (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Extensions.html)

**EDIT**

After you updated the answer ... well, obviously you have a private inheritance from a class. But please note, this is a terrible macro you have there because

```
#define CHECKLEAKDCL  : private CheckLeak
```

adds an `:` in your class declaration so you cannot use that symbol anymore to inherit  from base classes.

I'd recommend that you get rid of that macro altogether, if you cannot, do  not use it, it will confuse your code.

Comment: Just starting learning C++. With this macro, I will unable to use `:` anymore to inherit any class?

Answer (score 1):

We cannot tell exactly what it is, as we have even less information than you do.

Normally, I have seen such macros resolve to export macro, for the library.

That is, the value of it should be defined as `dllexport`, `dllimport` or `extern` (depending on platform). **When that is the case though, the macro appears before the class name.**

Considering the macro appears after the class name, **it can only resolve to a base class**, or **list of base classes**, or an empty macro.

If you have the documentation, search for a base class that tracks or reports it's address to a memory tracker on construction and destruction.

Then, the code base should be compiled using a macrodefinition similar to this:

```
#define CHECKLEAKDCL() : private MemoryTrackingBaseClass
```

(where `MemoryTrackingBaseClass` is the class I mentioned above - according to your edit, `CheckLeak`).

If you want to simply compile, try using:

```
#define CHECKLEAKDCL()
```

**Edit** (addressing your update)

> So Foo is extending CheckLeak, right?

Only when you want to check your application for leaks, using whatever `CheckLeak` implements.

In a production environment (after you use the definition inheriting from `CheckLeak`), you should probably define `CHECKLEAKDCL` as an empty macro (for speed).

Answer (score 0):

As you've discovered, `CHECKLEAKDCL` is a macro that expands to the three tokens `: private CheckLeak`. Presumably `CheckLeak` is a class that adds some leak checking diagnostic behaviour to classes which inherit from it.

In general, this sort of obfuscation is not very helpful. Depending on the properties of `CheckLeak`, this macro might have unintended side effects, such as turning what appears to be a standard layout class into a non-standard layout class.

It would also be hard to add `CHECKLEAKDCL` to a class that wanted to inherit from another class for any other reason. (Are you supposed to `class Foo CHECKLEAKDCL, public OtherBase` ?)

Personally, if given the chance to improve this project I'd favour replacing this macro with its actual expansion in this case.